# Error String index out of range: 1989045

Tags: java

Tengo este codigo y al meter los datos me da error. String index out of range: 1989045 no se donde puede ir el error son datos muy tontos y por mas que miro no lo veo. El unico error que se me ocurria era la cuenta bancaria y la elimine para que no la pidiera pero sigue danto.

```
class EntradaCliente {

    int numdias, factura;
    String dni, nombre, fecha, dias, cuenta;
    private static final String LETRAS_DNI = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";

    void validarEntrada() {
        // para leer del teclado
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre y los dos apellidos del cliente (en mayÃºsculas y sin acentos):");
            String nombre = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce el DNI del cliente (Formato 00000000A):");
            dni = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce la fecha de entrada (Formato DD/MM/AAAA):");
            fecha = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce los dias de estancia (de 1 a 28):");
            dias = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce El IBAN");
            cuenta = sc.nextLine();
            boolean error = false;
            if (compruebaNombre(nombre)) {
                System.out.println("El nombre esta mal");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!CompruebaDNI(dni)) {
                System.out.println("El DNI esta mal");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!validarFecha(fecha)) {
                System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!validarDias(dias)) {
                System.out.println("Los dÃ­as estÃ¡n mal");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!comprobarCuenta(cuenta)) {
                if (!error) {
                    calcularFacturaYGrabarDatos();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    boolean compruebaNombre(String nombre) {
        Pattern pat = null;
        Matcher mat = null;
        pat = Pattern.compile("[a-z]* [a-z]* [a-z]*");
        mat = pat.matcher(nombre);
        return mat.matches();
    }

    boolean CompruebaDNI(String dni) {
        Pattern pat = null;
        Matcher mat = null;
        pat = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[A-Z]");
        mat = pat.matcher(dni);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(dni.substring(0, 8));
            String let = dni.substring(9);
            return LETRAS_DNI.substring(num % 23, num / 23 + 1).equals(let);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    boolean validarFecha(String fecha) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            formatoFecha.setLenient(false);
            formatoFecha.parse(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean validarDias(String dias) {
        numdias = Integer.parseInt(dias);
        return (numdias > 1 && numdias <= 30);
    }

    void calcularFacturaYGrabarDatos() {
        // 40 euros por dÃ­a
        factura = 40 * numdias;
        System.out.println("La factura de su estancia asciende a 40 euros/dÃ­a: " + factura);
        // si estÃ¡ al menos una semana tiene un 5% de descuento por cada semana completa
        if (numdias > 7) {
            System.out.println("Se aplica un descuento del 5% por cada semana completa");
            factura -= factura * 0.05 * numdias / 7;
            // aÃ±adimos el iva 21%
            factura *= 1.21;
            System.out.println("La factura total con IVA 21% asciende a: " + factura);
        }
        //Imprimimos IBAN
        System.out.println("Número de cuenta " + cuenta);
        // se simula la grabaciÃ³n
        System.out.println("Los datos se han grabado correctamente");
    }

    public boolean comprobarCuenta(String cuenta) {

        boolean esValido = false;
        int i = 2;
        int caracterASCII = 0;
        int resto = 0;
        int dc = 0;
        String cadenaDc = "";
        BigInteger cuentaNumero = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger modo = new BigInteger("97");

        if (cuenta.length() == 24 && cuenta.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase().equals("E")
                && cuenta.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase().equals("S")) {

            do {
                caracterASCII = cuenta.codePointAt(i);
                esValido = (caracterASCII > 47 && caracterASCII < 58);
                i++;
            } while (i < cuenta.length() && esValido);

            if (esValido) {
                cuentaNumero = new BigInteger(cuenta.substring(4, 24) + "142800");
                resto = cuentaNumero.mod(modo).intValue();
                dc = 98 - resto;
                cadenaDc = String.valueOf(dc);
            }

            if (dc < 10) {
                cadenaDc = "0" + cadenaDc;
            }

            // Comparamos los caracteres 2 y 3 de la cuenta (dígito de control IBAN) con cadenaDc
            if (cuenta.substring(2, 4).equals(cadenaDc)) {
                esValido = true;
            } else {
                esValido = false;
            }
        }

        return esValido;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
        new EntradaCliente().validarEntrada();
     }
}
```

Este es el codigo espero podais ayudarme

Comment: El JVM te indicará la línea (una parte del código) que provoca la excepción.

Comment: que es jvm?donde viene eso?

Comment: El JVM significa Java Virtual Machine, la máquina virtual de Java es el encargado de traducir el archivo de tipo .class a código binario. Es decir, el JVM te avisará en que línea se provocó la excepción.

Comment: si te refieres al compilador no me dice nada de linea solo me dice ese error es mas el depurador no va linea a linea me pide los datos y da ese error al final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te está pasando porque al comprobar el dni, tu haces un `substring` en la posición 10 (sé que pones 9, pero en verdad estás mirando la 10, ya que substring empieza a mirar **a partir de la posición que la indiques (posicion que tu indicas no incluida)**, y estás suponiendo que el DNI tiene 10 posiciones, lo que puede no pasar, debes hacer esa comprobación primero. Por otro lado la línea: `return LETRAS_DNI.substring(num % 23, num / 23 + 1).equals(let);` no es correcta. Te paso el código con la corrección:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new EntradaCliente().validarEntrada();
 }
}
class EntradaCliente {

    int numdias, factura;
    String dni, nombre, fecha, dias, cuenta;
    private static final String LETRAS_DNI = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";

    void validarEntrada() {
        // para leer del teclado
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduce el nombre y los dos apellidos del cliente (en mayÃºsculas y sin acentos):");
            String nombre = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce el DNI del cliente (Formato 00000000A):");
            dni = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce la fecha de entrada (Formato DD/MM/AAAA):");
            fecha = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce los dias de estancia (de 1 a 28):");
            dias = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce El IBAN");
            cuenta = sc.nextLine();
            boolean error = false;
            if (compruebaNombre(nombre)) {
                System.out.println("El nombre esta mal");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!CompruebaDNI(dni)) {
                System.out.println("El DNI esta mal");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!validarFecha(fecha)) {
                System.out.println("Fecha incorrecta");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!validarDias(dias)) {
                System.out.println("Los dias estan mal");
                error = true;
            }
            if (!comprobarCuenta(cuenta)) {
                if (!error) {
                    calcularFacturaYGrabarDatos();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    boolean compruebaNombre(String nombre) {
        Pattern pat = null;
        Matcher mat = null;
        pat = Pattern.compile("[a-z]* [a-z]* [a-z]*");
        mat = pat.matcher(nombre);
        return mat.matches();
    }

    boolean CompruebaDNI(String dni) {
        if(dni.length()!=9){
            return false;
        }
        Pattern pat = null;
        Matcher mat = null;
        pat = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[A-Z]");
        mat = pat.matcher(dni);

        if (mat.matches()) {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(dni.substring(0, 8));
            String let = dni.substring(8);
            int posLetra=num % 23;
            return LETRAS_DNI.substring(posLetra, posLetra + 1).equals(let);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    boolean validarFecha(String fecha) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            formatoFecha.setLenient(false);
            formatoFecha.parse(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean validarDias(String dias) {
        try{
        numdias = Integer.parseInt(dias);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
        return (numdias > 1 && numdias <= 30);
    }

    void calcularFacturaYGrabarDatos() {
        // 40 euros por dÃ­a
        factura = 40 * numdias;
        System.out.println("La factura de su estancia asciende a 40 euros/dÃ­a: " + factura);
        // si estÃ¡ al menos una semana tiene un 5% de descuento por cada semana completa
        if (numdias > 7) {
            System.out.println("Se aplica un descuento del 5% por cada semana completa");
            factura -= factura * 0.05 * numdias / 7;
            // aÃ±adimos el iva 21%
            factura *= 1.21;
            System.out.println("La factura total con IVA 21% asciende a: " + factura);
        }
        //Imprimimos IBAN
        System.out.println("Número de cuenta " + cuenta);
        // se simula la grabaciÃ³n
        System.out.println("Los datos se han grabado correctamente");
    }

    public boolean comprobarCuenta(String cuenta) {

        boolean esValido = false;
        int i = 2;
        int caracterASCII = 0;
        int resto = 0;
        int dc = 0;
        String cadenaDc = "";
        BigInteger cuentaNumero = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger modo = new BigInteger("97");

        if (cuenta.length() == 24 && cuenta.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase().equals("E")
                && cuenta.substring(1, 2).toUpperCase().equals("S")) {

            do {
                caracterASCII = cuenta.codePointAt(i);
                esValido = (caracterASCII > 47 && caracterASCII < 58);
                i++;
            } while (i < cuenta.length() && esValido);

            if (esValido) {
                cuentaNumero = new BigInteger(cuenta.substring(4, 24) + "142800");
                resto = cuentaNumero.mod(modo).intValue();
                dc = 98 - resto;
                cadenaDc = String.valueOf(dc);
            }

            if (dc < 10) {
                cadenaDc = "0" + cadenaDc;
            }

            // Comparamos los caracteres 2 y 3 de la cuenta (dígito de control IBAN) con cadenaDc
            if (cuenta.substring(2, 4).equals(cadenaDc)) {
                esValido = true;
            } else {
                esValido = false;
            }
        }

        return esValido;
    }

}
```

La linea del `Let` si te fijas bien por un lado haces num % 23 (que es correcto) y por otro lado haces esto: num / 23 + 1, (que no es correcto) tendría que ser num % 23 +1, entonces para no hacerlo dos veces, lo mejor es sacarlo a una variable `posLetra`.

Ahora bien, divide esto: 50000000 (es un número de DNI válido) / 23 ¿cuanto da?, cierra la calculadora anda, que ya lo he hecho yo :) : 2.173.913,043478261. ¿Tiene todas esas posiciones el `String` LETRAS_DNI? No, sólo tiene 23, ahí es donde te daba `Error String index out of range: 1989045`.

Comment: si he entendido bien el erro esta en que el substring comineza mirar apartir del 10 porque aunque yo ponga 9 ese no cuenta no? y la linea del let que le ocurria?

Comment: Edito la respuesta para explicartelo que no me entra en el comentario